# Should a function creating a SharedFlow expose or not expose SharedFlow or SharedFlow specific features?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow, kotlin-sharedflow

Consider the following code:

```
fun CoroutineScope.createExposedSharedFlow(): SharedFlow<Int> {
    return flow<Int> { }.shareIn(this, started = SharingStarted.Lazily)
}

fun CoroutineScope.createEncapsulatedSharedFlow(): Flow<Int> {
    return flow<Int> { }.shareIn(this, started = SharingStarted.Lazily)
}

fun CoroutineScope.createEncapsulatedSharedFlow(onSubscription: suspend FlowCollector<Int>.() -> Unit): Flow<Int> {
    return flow<Int> { }.shareIn(this, started = SharingStarted.Lazily).onSubscription(onSubscription)
}

suspend fun useFlows() = coroutineScope {
    createExposedSharedFlow().onSubscription {
        // do something
    }

    createEncapsulatedSharedFlow().onSubscription {
        // does not compile
    }

    createEncapsulatedSharedFlow {
        // do something
    }
}
```

What is the best way to work with SharedFlow?

1. Exposing `SharedFlow` completely, thereby exposing an implementation detail of the function.
2. Not exposing `SharedFlow`, thereby losing access to `onSubscribe` and other `SharedFlow` specific functionality outside the function.
3. Not exposing `SharedFlow`, but exposing `onSubscribe` as a parameter to the function.